# Can "just" be used to mean "only"?

Tags: word-choice

When speaking of something done by somebody, can I say "She just did that." to mean "She only did that." (i.e. she didn't do anything else)?

I am asking because in Italian I can use the same word where English uses *only* and *just*. What would change is the position of the word. (Compare *lo ha **appena** fatto* with *ha fatto **appena** quello*.)

Comment: kiam, there is something wrong in "What would change is the position of the word." What did you mean?

Comment: @Carlo That sentence is fine.  It can be paraphrased as "The position of the word is what would change.", though the emphasis is slightly different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can say something like...

> *"She just washed the dishes"*

...but what exactly you mean is entirely context-dependent - you could continue with either of...

> 1: *...but she didn't dry them and put them away*.
>    2: *...a few minutes ago*.

Outside of context there's not normally any way to establish whether *just* means *only a little while ago* or *only that and nothing else*.

---

Regarding OP's secondary question about the meaning being affected by word position...

> *"She washed just the dishes"*

...could *only* mean ***only/nothing but*** the dishes (she didn't wash the pots and pans). But so far as I can see this doesn't lead us to any useful general principle, given that...

> 3: *"I just found out this morning."*
>   and
>    4: *"I found out just this morning."*

...effectively mean exactly the same in most contexts (contrary to what might have been expected, I didn't know [whatever] until this morning). But there is a case for saying #3 is more suitable when emphasising that [whatever] is some piece of trivial information you happened to come across, and #4 fits better when you want to emphasise *how recently* you discovered whatever it was.

To summarise: for any given context, the position of "just" might affect meaning (subtly *or* decisively), but it's not obvious to me this leads to any useful general principles. In essence, "context is everything".

Comment: I would say 2 is the default interpretation (occurs when the statement is context-free), and context can potentially change it to 1.  Because of this, *just* can't always replace *only*, which can express 1 without context.

Comment: @snailplane: I don't necessarily have an opinion on which is the "default" - I'm just saying that it could be *either*, depending on context. Which example incidentally leads me to suspect that when coupled with a *present tense* verb, *only* might well be the "default". That's enough messing about; the truth is I don't think it's meaningful to talk about a *default* in the first place. In almost all real-world contexts it's obviously one meaning or the other, and it's largely irrelevant to debate which sense actually occurs "more often".

Comment: I said nothing about which occurs "more often".  I defined "default interpretation" parenthetically as "occurs when the statement is context-free".

Comment: @snailplane: oic. Well I suppose (for this particular *word*, at least) I guess we just have to agree to differ. I think it makes no more sense to speak of a "default interpretation" for ***just*** than it does for, say, ***set*** or ***him***. The former mainly because it has so many meanings, the latter because it has no real meaning out of context.

Comment: I dunno. Even if you say "She just washed the dishes, not the pots and pans", I will first try to parse it as "just now" (so the sentence is emphasizing that what she washed just now was the dishes, not the pots and pans). If I unequivocally want to imply "only", I'll use that word (or "merely", or some other word that can't mean anything time-related).

Comment: @Martha,snailplane: I think this is wishful thinking based on how unambiguous you'd *like* [us] to be. GB: [I just asked that's all](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+just+asked+that's+all%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):628 hits, [ditto **only**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+only+asked+that's+all%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):7 hits, [ditto **merely**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+merely+asked+that's+all%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):2 hits. Mostly, people just use *just* for all senses, justifiably or not.